# Populate mat-select option from JSON file

Tags: json, angular, http

I tried to populate mat-select options from JSON file, but appears a error like

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 8584 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad

I created a service to get list:

```
getCountries(): Observable<ICountry[]>{
    return this.http.get<ICountry[]>(this._url);
  }
```

Here I tried to populate the array:

```
this._countriesService.getCountries()
      .subscribe(data => this.countries = data,
                error => console.log(error));
```

and the html code looks like:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Country From</mat-label>
<mat-select>
<mat-option>None</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.name">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

JSON file:

```
[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}, 
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}, 
  {"name": "AndorrA", "code": "AD"}, 
  {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"}, 
  {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"}, 
  {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"}, 
  {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"}, 
  {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"}, 
  {"name": "Armenia", "code": "AM"}, 
  {"name": "Aruba", "code": "AW"}, 
  {"name": "Australia", "code": "AU"}, 
  {"name": "Austria", "code": "AT"}, 
  {"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ"}
]
```

And I need to show all names to mat-select.
Thank you.

Comment: produce a stackblitz

Comment: I created the following stack blitz and its working.. Check if  the data you're getting is the actual data https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-nxxdua?file=app/select-form-example.html